# Twitter user search with API 1.1: limit the number of results and paging

Tags: api, rest, twitter

When performing user search with the new Twitter API (can be checked here https://dev.twitter.com/console), found the problem with limiting the number of returned results, as well as with paging.
So, let's say I want to get 5 results from searching and use count parameter:

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=Online&count=5

It works correctly, returns 5 records. But if I set count to zero, there is still one result returned:

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=Online&count=0

Is it expected?

Then i tried to use paging for the same purposes (wanted to get the first page, and limit results in it):

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=Online&per_page=5&page=1

Now it looks like the limit doesn't work at all, there are much more than 5 records returned. 
Does anybody know if something is wrong with the queries, or it's an API bug?

Answer (score 1):

**Try like this : **
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json

**Parameters:**

1) page : Specifies the page

2) count : Number of user results to retrieve per page and max is 20.

Following example will return 1 result from page 2 for search keyword "wordpress"

```
<?php
require_once('api/TwitterAPIExchange.php');
require_once("token.php"); // For your access token - viral

$searchword = "wordpress";

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json';
$getfield = '?&page=2&count=1&q='.$searchword;

$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$followers = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();

$json = json_decode($followers, true);

print_r($json);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the 'per_page' is not a valid parameter in this 1.1 API.
And then, it returns the default number 20.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/search